# Installing Ubuntu 17.10 on Acer Aspire E 15 E5-575G-55F8

Tags: dual-boot, acer, 17.10

I have Acer Aspire E 15 E5-575G-55F8 with 2 hard drives. I want  to use one hard drive for Windows 10, and one for Ubuntu:

[image: drive layouts]

I put Ubuntu 17.10 on a USB stick and booted from it. Then selected that I want both Windows and Ubuntu. The installation program wanted to reboot so I clicked Continue and this was the message I got:

[image: kworker blocked for more than 120 seconds]

Then after 10 minutes, Acer booted Windows. I tried the same again, but still the same message, and I cant see Ubuntu anywhere.

**Edits**:

In BIOS I cant see Ubuntu, but I can see Windows Boot Loader.

[image: boot order in BIOS/UEFI]

Seems like Ubuntu didn't get installed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok well. reboot your machine once again(Before do that make sure you know the Boot Menu page hotkey). Ex I'm using ASAS, it has <kbd>F8</kbd> key to Boot Menu.

> **As I Know [Acer use <kbd>F12</kbd> for Boot Order](http://www.killdisk.com/bootdisk-bootmenu.htm)**

Something similar to this

[image]

And Navigate to <kbd>Boot</kbd> in the menu(in above image `Tab` will work to switch) and select boot loader(1st) to **`Ubuntu`** and Save it.

on reboot, you can see something like this.

[image]

Comment: Tried this, did not see Ubuntu. https://i.imgur.com/nf8dFKY.jpg

Comment: @Solo as [you posted in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6A8r.png) you should set `HDD1` as default

Comment: Setting HDD1 as default in BIOS did not work. For me it seems like the boot loader did not manage to write the boot program ? Where is the boot program stored?

Comment: is your both hards are mounted? or its and external drive ?

Comment: Bios key is `F2` better have look at that too

Comment: My guess is that it may have something to do with Acer UEFI  mode. It seems that it is very difficult to have Windows and Ubuntu with UEFI  mode.